# CSS3 flex: input box specific width, input box is overflowing

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

Could someone shed some light on this jsFiddle behaviour? http://jsfiddle.net/zZgmn/1/

What I want to do is have the `input[type=text]` box to be a specific width. However, with the flex-direction set to row, the input box refuses to change size.

If however you set the flex-direction to column, you can see that the text box will change to the specified width?

If I take off the width, I would imagine that the text box should flex to fill the content if it can, but it doesn't.

I seem to be missing something.

I've tried many variations, but the one I understand should work for setting the width is `-webkit-flex:0 0 32px;` But this does not seem to have any bearing.

**Edit**

This image shows the rendered input box. It is not 5px wide.
[image: Input Overflow]

This image shows the rendered flex area of the parent into which the input box should fit inside.
[image: Parent Width]

Comment: It seems like a number input element would be more appropriate here than trying to create your own (`<input type="number" />`).

Answer (score 6):

Got it!

So you have to add a size to your input box. `<input type="text" size="2" />`

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you! This put and end to some frustrating troubleshooting.